# Control remotely on windows processes - kill and execute

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a program which needs to open and close processes on remote machines - windows machines - all kind (7, 2000, xp)
How this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this belongs on SU or SF.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`taskkill` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602%28WS.10%29.aspx) with the `/s` argument.